# Cannot instantiate class in java

Tags: java

I'm new in programming and just started java programming.
In Main.java file I'm trying to instantiate class Car, but I've got Error: java: not a statement and Error:java: ';' expected

This is Car.java file

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Car {

  double averageMilesPerGallon;
  String licensePlate;
  Color paintColor;
  boolean areTaillightsWorking;

  public Car(double inputAverageMPG,
             String inputLicensePlate,
             Color inputPaintColor,
             boolean inputAreTaillightsWorking) {
    this.averageMilesPerGallon = inputAverageMPG;
    this.licensePlate = inputLicensePlate;
    this.paintColor = inputPaintColor;
    this.areTaillightsWorking = inputAreTaillightsWorking;
  }
}
```

This is Main.java file

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Car myCar = new Car(inputAverageMPG: 25.5,
                        inputLicensePlate: "1BC32E",
                        Color.BLUE,
                        inputAreTaillightsWorking: true);

  }
}
```

The errors are shown on `inputAverageMPG`, `inputLicensePlate` and `inputAreTaillightsWorking`.

Please give me some advice so I could make things work!

Comment: [Java is to JavaScript as ham is to hamster](http://javascriptisnotjava.com/)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You have tagged three languages in your question, which makes your question unclear.  Unless your question is actually about three different languages, please [edit] your question to remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: And also have a look at the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling a method in Java, you don't pass arguments with their names.  So instead of `inputAverageMPG: 25.5,`, just `25.5` will do.